Getting error Window is not defined in Next app
I am tring to run a next app, but it is giving me the error "window is not defined". I tried to fix it, but then it proceded to give me another error
My initial code:
store.tsx:
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { create } from "zustand";
import { EVMWallet } from "@catalogfi/wallets";
import { BrowserProvider,Wallet,JsonRpcProvider} from "ethers";

import { GardenJS } from "@gardenfi/core";
import { Orderbook, Chains,TESTNET_ORDERBOOK_API} from "@gardenfi/orderbook";

import {
  BitcoinNetwork,
  BitcoinProvider,
  BitcoinOTA,
} from "@catalogfi/wallets";

type EvmWalletState = {
  metaMaskIsConnected: boolean;
  evmProvider: BrowserProvider | null;
};

type EvmWalletAction = {
  connectMetaMask: () => Promise<void>;
};

const networkConfig = {
  chainId: "0xaa36a7",
  chainName: "Sepolia",
  rpcUrls: ["https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/"],
  nativeCurrency: {
    symbol: "SepoliaETH",
    decimals: 18,
  },
};

const useMetaMaskStore = create<EvmWalletState & EvmWalletAction>((set) => ({
  metaMaskIsConnected: false,
  evmProvider: null,
  connectMetaMask: async () => {
    if (window.ethereum !== null) {
      let provider = new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
      let network = await provider.getNetwork();
      console.log("network: ",network);
      
      if (network.chainId !== 11155111n) {
        await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
          params: [networkConfig],
        });
        provider = new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
      }
      set(() => ({
        evmProvider: provider,
        metaMaskIsConnected: true,
      }));
    } else {
      throw new Error("MetaMask not Found");
    }
  },
}));



const signer = await new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum).getSigner();
const evmWallet = new EVMWallet(signer);

const provider = new BitcoinProvider(BitcoinNetwork.Testnet);
//const signer = await new BrowserProvider(window.ethereum).getSigner();
const bitcoinWallet = new BitcoinOTA(provider, signer);

type GardenStore = {
  garden: GardenJS | null;
  bitcoin: BitcoinOTA | null;
  ethereum: EVMWallet | null;
  setGarden: (garden: GardenJS, bitcoin: BitcoinOTA, ethereum: EVMWallet) => void;
};

const gardenStore = create<GardenStore>((set) => ({
  garden: null,
  bitcoin: bitcoinWallet,
  ethereum:evmWallet,
  setGarden: (garden: GardenJS, bitcoin: BitcoinOTA,ethereum:EVMWallet) => {
    set(() => ({
      garden,
      bitcoin,
      ethereum
    }));
  },
}));

type SignStore = {
  isMMPopupOpen: boolean;
  isSigned: boolean;
  setIsMMPopupOpen: (isMMPopupOpen: boolean) => void;
  setIsSigned: (isSigned: boolean) => void;
};

const useSignStore = create<SignStore>((set) => ({
  isMMPopupOpen: false,
  isSigned: false,
  setIsMMPopupOpen: (isMMPopupOpen: boolean) => {
    set(() => {
      return { isMMPopupOpen };
    });
  },
  setIsSigned: (isSigned: boolean) => {
    set(() => {
      return { isSigned };
    });
  },
}));

const useGarden = () => ({
  garden: gardenStore((state) => state.garden),
  bitcoin: gardenStore((state) => state.bitcoin),
  ethereum: gardenStore((state)=>state.ethereum)
});

/* Only to be used once at the root level*/
const useGardenSetup = () => {
  const { evmProvider } = useMetaMaskStore();
  const { setGarden } = gardenStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!evmProvider) return;
      const signer = await evmProvider.getSigner();

      // const bitcoinProvider = new BitcoinProvider(
      //   BitcoinNetwork.Testnet,
      //   "http://localhost:30000"
      // );

      const orderbook = await Orderbook.init({
        url: TESTNET_ORDERBOOK_API,
        signer,
        // opts: {
        //   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        //   domain: (window as any).location.host,
        //   store: localStorage,
          
        // },
      });

      const wallets = {
        [Chains.bitcoin_testnet]: bitcoinWallet,
        [Chains.ethereum_sepolia]: evmWallet,
        
      };

      const garden = new GardenJS(orderbook, wallets);

      setGarden(garden, wallets[Chains.bitcoin_testnet],wallets[Chains.ethereum_sepolia]);
    })();
  }, [evmProvider, setGarden]);
};

export { useMetaMaskStore, useGarden, useGardenSetup, useSignStore };


I tried using typeof window !== "undefined" && window.ethereum !== null, but it is then giving the error once the initial error was fixed
1 of 3 unhandled errors

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Token Details" Client: "Wrapped Tokens Import"

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Component Stack
li
ol
Stepper
div
tokenize
StateContextProvider
AnonAadhaarProvider
Le
Web3ContextProvider
ConnectKitProvider
QueryClientProvider
Hydrate
WagmiProvider
Web3Provider
App
Call Stack
checkForUnmatchedText
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (9647:0)
didNotMatchHydratedTextInstance
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (11394:0)
prepareToHydrateHostTextInstance
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (12606:0)
completeWork
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22232:0)
completeUnitOfWork
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26596:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26568:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26466:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26434:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25738:0)
workLoop
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (266:0)
flushWork
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (239:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (533:0)

tokenize.jsx:
import { useState } from "react";
import TokenDetailsComponent from "../Components/TokenDetailsComponent";
import ChooseChainComponent from "../Components/ChooseChainComponent";
import ToWBTCComponent from "./toWBTCComponent";
import { Button } from "flowbite-react";
import { useAccount } from "wagmi";

const Stepper = () => {
    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(1);
    const account = useAccount();

    const stepperOptions = [
        {
            label: 1,
            value: 'Chain of Deployment'
        },
        {
            label: 2,
            value: 'Wrapped Tokens Import'
        },
        {
            label: 3,
            value: 'Token Details'
        },
        { 
            label: 4,
            value: 'Confirmation'
        }
    ];

    const renderStepContent = () => {
        switch(currentStep) {
            case 1:
                return <ChooseChainComponent />;
            case 2:
                return <ToWBTCComponent/>;
            case 3:
                return  <TokenDetailsComponent />;
            // Add cases for other steps as needed
            default:
                return null;
        }
    };

    const handleNext = () => {
        if (currentStep < stepperOptions.length) {
            setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
        }
    };

    const handlePrevious = () => {
        if (currentStep > 1) {
            setCurrentStep(currentStep - 1);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <ol className="flex items-center flex-row justify-center w-full p-3 space-x-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 sm:text-base sm:p-4 sm:space-x-4 rtl:space-x-reverse">
                {stepperOptions.map((option, index) => {
                    if (option.label === 2 && account.chainId !== 11155111) {
                        // Do not render the "Wrapped Tokens Import" option if the selected chain is not Sepolia
                        return null;
                    }

                    return (
                        <li key={index} className={`flex items-center ${currentStep === option.label ? 'text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500' : 'text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400'}`}>
                            <span className="flex items-center justify-center w-5 h-5 me-2 text-xs border border-blue-600 rounded-full shrink-0 dark:border-blue-500">
                            {option.label > 2 ? (account.chainId === 11155111 ? option.label: option.label-1) : option.label}
                            </span>

                            {option.value}
                            {option.label !== 4 && (
                                <svg className="w-3 h-3 ms-2 sm:ms-4 rtl:rotate-180" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 12 10">
                                    <path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="m7 9 4-4-4-4M1 9l4-4-4-4"/>
                                </svg>
                            )}
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ol>
            <div className="step-content">
                {renderStepContent()}
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between mt-4">
                <Button color='purple' onClick={handlePrevious} disabled={currentStep === 1} className="btn btn-secondary">
                    Previous
                </Button>
                <Button color='purple' onClick={handleNext} disabled={currentStep === stepperOptions.length} className="btn btn-primary">
                    Next
                </Button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Stepper;



You can try using, window?. In place of window. all places, ex - window?.ethereum

I guess you're trying to use client-side logic without 'use client'.
